# Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate): ASP.NET Web Service - Debug Breakpoint does not hit. Not able to Debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Recently, I've installed VS 2010 on my machine. I also have VS 2008 installed.

Problem I'm facing is - I'm not able to debug the web services hosted on local IIS. **Also, VS 2010 do not show message that source code is different.**
To start debugging I'm attaching aspnet_wp.exe process. My breakpoint is in a method which is part of a Class Library project which is targeting to .NET v3.5.

Environment Details:
   - Windows XP SP3
   - VS 2005, 2008 & 2010
   - IIS (v5.1) Targeting ASP.NET 2.0
   - Web Service Targeting .NET Framework - v3.5

Does anybody have encountered same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is an easiest method than attaching, to use the

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Next, go to the IIS and open the properties on you running web and check on "Web Site" tab if the the "HTTP Keep-Alives" is enable or not, and make it not enable.

If still not break, close the vs, and go to the project directory, and delete (first backup it) the **xxxxx.suo** file of the project. Then start it again and go for debug.